# Placing and scaling of elements depending on screen size and zoom factor

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple webpage in HTML with two elements. The first element is a chat window where users can chat. The second element is a chart.js plot. The HTML looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  <section class="msger">
    <header class="msger-header">
       <div class="msger-header-title">
         <!-- Here are several buttons included -->
       </div>
    </header>
    <main class="msger-chat">
        <!-- Here is the main window of the chat -->
        <div class="container" id="start-btn">
          <button class="start-btn" type="button" onClick="start()">
            Start Conversation
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg left-msg">
        </div>
    </main>

    <form class="msger-inputarea" id="msger-input">
       <input type="text" class="msger-input" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter your message..." style="display:none">
       <button type="submit" class="msger-send-btn" style="display:none" id="sendInput">Send</button>
     </form>

  </section>

  <div style="height: 50vh; width: 50%;">
        <!-- This is the chart.js plot -->
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS file is as follows:

```
:root {
    --body-bg: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
    --msger-bg: #fff;
    --border: 2px solid #ddd;
    --left-msg-bg: #ececec;
    --right-msg-bg: #579ffb;
  }

  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }

  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: var(--body-bg);
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  .msger {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 867px;
    margin: 25px 10px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: var(--border);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: var(--msger-bg);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .msger-header {
    /* display: flex; */
    font-size: medium;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    background: #eee;
    color: #666;
  }

  .msger-chat {
    background-color: #fcfcfe;
  }

.container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
}

.start-btn {
    background: #239630;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.23s;
    border: none;
    font-size: xx-large;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.start-btn:hover {
    background: rgb(87, 159, 251);
}

  .msger-inputarea {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: var(--border);
    background: #eee;
  }
  .msger-inputarea * {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .msger-input {
    flex: 1;
    background: #ddd;
  }

  .msger-send-btn {
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #579ffb;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.23s;
  }
  .msger-send-btn:hover {
    background: rgb(0, 180, 50);
  }
```

I'm now facing three problems:

- The chart.js plot is placed to the right of the chat window. This is good on big screens but does not work on small screens (e.g. mobile). Is it possible to put the chart.js plot on the right for larger screens and for smaller screens below the chat window?
- The chart.js plot is now relative wide compared to the chat window. Is it possible to make the chat window width 60% and the chart.js plot width 40% and scale the height of the plot accordingly?
- When I zoom out the webpage (e.g. 50%), the width of the chat window is getting smaller and the width of the chart.js plot is getting bigger. Is it possible to keep the width of the chat window and chart.js plot constant when zooming?

Answer (score 2):

To address your three problems:

Placing the chart.js plot below the chat window on smaller screens can be achieved by using media queries in CSS. You can define different styles for different screen sizes. Here's an example of how you can modify your CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .msger {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .msger-chat {
    order: 2;
  }

  .msger-inputarea {
    order: 3;
  }

  .chart-container {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

In the HTML code, wrap the chart.js plot `<div>` with a container element and give it a class like chart-container.

```html
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

This will make the chart.js plot appear below the chat window on screens with a maximum width of 768 pixels.

To make the chat window 60% wide and the chart.js plot 40% wide, you can modify the CSS styles for the `.msger` and `.chart-container` classes. Adjust the width property as follows:

```css
.msger {
  width: 60%;
}

.chart-container {
  width: 40%;
}
```

This will set the width of the chat window to 60% and the chart.js plot to 40% of the available space.

To keep the widths of the chat window and chart.js plot constant when zooming, you can use the min-width property to set a minimum width for the `.msger` and `.chart-container` classes. Add the following CSS styles:

```css
.msger {
  min-width: 500px;
}

.chart-container {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

These styles will ensure that the chat window and chart.js plot maintain a minimum width even when the page is zoomed out.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:

You can try an alternative approach by using CSS flexbox and the `flex-wrap` property.

Here's an updated CSS code snippet:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .msger {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .msger-chat {
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .msger-inputarea {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .chart-container {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

By setting `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.msger` class, the chat window and input area will wrap to the next line if the available space is not sufficient horizontally.

Make sure you have the following HTML structure:

```html
<body>
  <section class="msger">
    <header class="msger-header">
      <!-- Header content -->
    </header>
    <div class="msger-chat">
      <!-- Chat window content -->
    </div>

    <form class="msger-inputarea" id="msger-input">
      <!-- Input area content -->
    </form>
  </section>

  <div class="chart-container">
    <!-- Chart.js plot -->
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

With this update, plot should be positioned below the chat window on smaller screens while maintaining its placement to the right of the chat window on larger screens like your mobile phone.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked well except for the placement of chart.js below the chat window. I added the CSS you proposed and edited the div element but on my Samsung S23 Ultra the chart.js plot is not put below the chat window. I assume because the resolution of the screen is too high (3088 x 1440). If I set the max-width to 1440, the placement would be below on my S23 but it would also be below on larger screens with lower resolution. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: So for example, my computer screen has a resolution of 2560 x 1440 and my S23 has a resolution of 3088 x 1440. So both devices have the same amount of pixel in the width. On my computer screen I would like to have the chart.js plot to the right of the chat window and on my S23 below the chat window (because the screen is much smaller).

Comment: I used min-width for .msger and .chart-container but the widths are not kept constant. The .msger window is get smaller and the .chart-container is getting larger when zooming out.

Comment: Another thing: The chart.js plot is also not floating below the chat window even when the media query is fulfilled.

Comment: I updated the answer, but i cannot see my updates. Strange

Comment: I also cannot see your edits. I could resolve the issue with zooming by setting min-width and max-width to 60% and 40% for .msger and .chart-container.

Comment: But the problem with the placement below the chat window I could not resolve (my first two comments above).

Comment: @BlackHawk can you see the update now? Does it help?

Comment: Yes, I can see it. But I don't want to wrap the chat window (.msger class) to the next line. I would like to wrap the chart-container to the next line if there is not enough space.